# Unexpected result when returning from JDialog

Tags: java, swing, repaint

I have a JFrame with a JPanel in it. This JPanel is essentially a drawing panel. 
I am showing a JDialog to enter various parameters like radius and position to draw a circle.
For showing JDialog i am using:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
{
    public void run()
    {
      dialog.setVisible(true);
    }
});
```

When the user presses the draw button on the jdialog, i dispose it (dialog.dispose();) and draw the circle based on the parameters entered by the user in Jdialog immediately after disposing.

The Circle draws but the JDialog also gets drawn erroneously. I am using repaint() call to draw the Circle. The painting gives desired result after i minimize and maximize the window:

[image]

Am i closing the Dialog in a wrong way?

Comment: How is your `paint***` methods of your `JPanel`?

Comment: I think you mean paintComponent(). I set the desired parameters values entered by the user into some variables inside the DrawingPanel class.
Then issue the repaint() call.
 I think the bad result is because i am doing the panel.repaint() from the JDialog thread.

Comment: Can you show its code? If you do not invoke `super.paintComponent(g)` and `opaque==true`, you must completely fill in the background in a non-opaque color. Otherwise you will likely see visual artifacts.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure

```
super.paintComponent();
```

is invoked when overriding `paintComponent` when doing custom painting in Swing. This call will correctly paint the custom paint area. Without this call, background components will remain visible

Comment: Booh i forgot that! So i guess there is nothing wrong with my showing and disposing of the JDialog?